# Import error:DLL load failed : The specificed module not found

Tags: python, torch

Iam using python version 3.7.8
I install torch version 1.3.1
For face emotional recognition
But finally I run this show error I didn't know how to rectified it can anyone help me please.

I using python version 3.7.8.
Install torch version 1.3.1 for face emotional recognition
But finally I run this error shows ,I didn't know how to rectified it can anyone help me please

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Pls read: [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Which DLL are you trying to import? What is the full stack trace? What packages are you importing and is there any code sample?